# Spring Data JPA lazy fetching with collections

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have an User entity with Set cars (oneToMany). Also I have a method:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Optional<User> getUserWithCars(Long id) {
    return userRepository.findOneById(id).map(u -> {
        u.getCars().size();
        return u;
    });
}
```

Lazy fetching works fine. But what if I have to fetch set of users with cars? I tried to use *users.forEach(u -> u.getCars().size());* but received a popular *no Session* exception.

P.S. I need lazy fetch, not eager.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable place to just write a query that returns the count from the server rather than invoking lots of round-trips when you know what you want ahead of time.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. I have to create a method that fetch es all users with cats from db and then returns them. I need it to use in controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in spring data jpa you can write query method

```
Optional<User> findFirstWithCarsById(Long id);
```

for more information look to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods)

Comment: I needed to query a collection of users, not a single user. However, the question is resolved.

Comment: @Feeco this one is also possible List<User> findWithCarsById(Long id);

I am writing it because someone else may have this issue

Answer (score 1):

In repository:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.cars")
public Set<User> getUserWithCars()
```

Comment: My method to fetch single User works too. I need a method to fetch Set<User> with cars.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope it explains, but im not sure i undertand you correctly.

Comment: For example, I have 2 users in my database. Each user has 2 cars. I need a method that fetch 2 users with their cars. Method return a set with 2 users, each has a set of cars (in our case, 2 cars for each user).

Comment: If the field `cars` in the `User` entity is a set then my method will get you a `Set` with embedded `Set`'s for `Cars`.

Comment: But getUserWithCars from repository returns Optional<User>, not Set<User>. How can I fetch all the users? And why the method in the service layer has an id as parameter? This method should return all of users, not only one by id.

Comment: Because you showed in your code that you look for users by id. I edited the code once again, but your question is not good at all.

Comment: I wrote that my method works, but I need a method for a users set, because this is the issue. I will accept your answer if it will work.